# 4-parameter logistic curve fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to perform a 4-parameter logistic (4PL) curve fit with scipy on data from a scientific assay. The goal is to get a fit that closely matches the results of the software I normally use.

Unfortunately, the lower part of the curve does not fit well, as shown in this figure.

[image]

I also tried to create a fit after applying a log10 transform to the x values, but I only get a straight line instead of a curve fit.

[image]

Below is my current code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

conc = np.array([300000, 70376.8, 16509.6, 3873.0, 908.6, 213.1, 50.0, 11.7])

ref = np.array([7.11469e+05, 2.16006e+05, 5.81840e+04, 1.39850e+04,
                3.21300e+03, 8.76000e+02, 2.54000e+02, 1.16000e+02])

# 4pl curve equation
def func(xdata, a, b, c, d): 
    return ((a-d)/(1.0+((xdata/c)**b))) + d

# Calculate example weights as 1/y^2
weights = 1 / (ref **2)

#set bounds
amin = 50 
bounds = ([ amin, -np.inf, -np.inf , -np.inf], [np.inf, np.inf, np.inf, np.inf])


# initial params
a = min(ref) * 0.9
d = max(ref) * 1.1
b = 1
c = (d-a)/2    
initial_guess = [a, b, c, d] 
print('Initial params:', initial_guess)


# # Perform the curve fit
params, params_covariance = curve_fit(func, conc, ref, p0=initial_guess, method='trf',sigma=weights, bounds=bounds, maxfev=100000)
print('params:', params)


# Generate y values from the fitted curve
x_fit = np.arange(min(conc), max(conc), 8) 
y_fit = func(x_fit, *params)

# # Plot the raw data and the fitted curve
#plt.scatter(conc_mlt, ref, label='Raw data')
plt.scatter(conc, ref , label='Weighted Data') #s=weights*100??
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, label='Fitted Curve')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: For this to be reproducible, you need to provide the `ref` data. I assume it's just an array the same length as `conc`

Comment: maybe start with setting bounds that are closer to reality. The curve_fit may not be fitting properly and diverges because it can; more realistic bounds might keep it in check and output a better fit.

Comment: @MrE Thanks for your comment. 

I have already tried changing the initial parameters but it does have no effect on the final parameters which is also something I do not understand ...


These are the initial and final parameters of the software I am normally using: 

`itinitial_guess = [608, 1, 6735.4, 271674.8]`
`params = np.array([71.9, 0.992, 662924, 2261496])`

Comment: Hey thank you for your comments @astroChance I am sorry, here is the experiment's signal data: 
`ref = np.array([7.11469e+05, 2.16006e+05, 5.81840e+04, 1.39850e+04, 3.21300e+03, 8.76000e+02, 2.54000e+02, 1.16000e+02])`

 Also remove this part of the code as it's a function I wrote which you do not need if you have the ref data: 

`from txtfile_todf import`
`get_txt_file conc = np.array([300000, 70376.8, 16509.6, 3873.0, 908.6, 213.1, 50.0, 11.7])`
`d = get_txt_file.conv_txtf('path to file')`
`ref = get_txt_file.ref_cruve(d) ref = np.array(ref)`

Comment: @MarieThoelke Please edit your question to include these additions so future people can find the content they need in the post rather than the comments.

Comment: Your function does not adhere to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function

Comment: Have you tried this [minimizer](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#using-the-minimizer-class) from [LMFIT](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) package? in first try  I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/nmLeJT0.jpg) but you might play with `minimizer()` class to optimize it possibly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently unsure of how to improve the fit of your lower values using `scipy`. However, if you don't *require* the use of your specific fitting function, you could potentially look at options like `numpy.polyfit`. Here is an example in case this could work for you:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

conc = np.array([300000, 70376.8, 16509.6, 3873.0, 908.6, 213.1, 50.0, 11.7])

ref = np.array([7.11469e+05, 2.16006e+05, 5.81840e+04, 1.39850e+04,
                3.21300e+03, 8.76000e+02, 2.54000e+02, 1.16000e+02])

## Trying NumPy Polyfit
np_fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(np.log(conc), np.log(ref), deg=4))
x_npfits = np.logspace(1, 6)
y_npfits = []
for i in x_npfits:
    y_npfits.append(np.exp(np_fit(np.log(i))))

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(conc, ref , label='Weighted Data')
plt.plot(x_npfits, y_npfits)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid("both")
plt.show()
```

Produces:

[image]